# Best way to maintain a config file for java application

Tags: java, config

I'm writing a java application that contains a lot of savable settings. Basically my config structure looks like this:

```
Config
|_ game 1
   |_ Game name: blah...
   |_ Player name: alice
   |_ Player name: bob
   |_ other settings...
|_ game 2
   |_ Game name: hah
   |_ Player name: alice
   |_ Player name: bob
   |_ other settings...
|_ game n....
```

You got the idea. I tried use xml but working with dom4j is a pain especially there are a lot of child nodes with the same name in different and same parent nodes and I need to change them a lot. So far the most hassle-less way I discover is use a plain text file like

```
[Game 1]
Game name: blah
Player name: alice
Player name: bob
...

[Game 2]
...
```

But I feel like this is very rudimentary. So what is the best or standard practice in industry for maintaining config files in java?

**EDIT** : I'd like the solution to be portable, like copy a file from one computer to another will not break the program. (Sorry forget mention this ahead.)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to store settings/preferences in java is to use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should have used automatic marshaller to write your XML file. A few years ago, I used [CastorXML](http://castor.codehaus.org/xml-framework.html) but today, there are probably more modern APIs to that purpose.

With this API, you basically :

- Store all your config in a simple POJO
- Instantiate a Marshaller
- Call marshaller.write(MyConfig)

When you want to load your config :

- Instantiate an Unmarshaller
- call Marshaller.read(yourFile)

You can describe the XML mapping in a configuration file or use a default Marshaller (1 attribute ~ 1 XML tag)

It is that simple.

EDIT:

After a search in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040233/what-is-the-difference-between-castor-xml-binding-and-jaxb-binding), JAXB specification came after the first realease of CastorXML and the Sun implementation of JAXB seems now to be a standard for `Java <-> XML` mapping.

Comment: The deal breaker here is that I have a lot of attributes with the same name, like the `player name`. So when I want to change `Alice` to `Leo`, I want to make sure that it doesn't overwrite `Bob` here. Can CastorXML guarantee that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [YAML](http://www.yaml.org) to define your configuration, it's much less verbose compared to XML, for example:

```
games:
  - name: 'game 1'
    players: ['Bob', 'Alice']
    ...
  - name: 'game 2'
    players: ['Bob', 'Alice']
    ...
```

You can then use the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library with the [YAML extension](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) to interact with the configuration, for example to parse the configuration:

```
File configFile = new File("...");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Configuration config = mapper.readValue(configFile, Configuration.class);
```

Comment: YAML is at least very portable between different stacks.  And this was one of the authors requisits.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/).

It provides good support for [hierarchical configurations](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration//userguide/howto_xml.html).

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("games.xml");
String gameName = config.getString("game1.name");
List<Object> playerNames = config.getList("game1.players.player.name");
// ...
config.setProperty("game1.name", "Space Invaders"); // update game name
config.addProperty("game1.players.player(-1).name", "ted"); // add new players
config.addProperty("game1.players.player(-1).name", "carol"); 
config.clearTree("game1.players.player(1)"); // remove a player

// Or with XPath 
config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());
config.addProperty("game1/players player/name", "ted"); 
config.addProperty("game1/players player/name", "carol"); 
config.clearTree("game1/players/player[2]");
```